# Android External File Inconsistently Appearing

Tags: java, android, file-io, storage, external

I'm using an IntentService to append single NMEA strings to a log file stored in the external public storage on an Android device, but I'm getting inconsistent behavior.

First off the log file does not appear when the device is connected for USB debugging. I read that many Android devices cannot write to external storage when connected via USB, but even when it is run disconnected from USB, it may take several times of turning it on and off and rerunning the applications before the log file appears in the file system. If I do not clear the log, I still have to restart the phone before it will begin appending to the file again.

How can I get the file to appear consistently everytime?

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;


public class LogFileService extends IntentService {

    DebugLog debug = new DebugLog("LogFileService");

    public static final String GPS_STR = "GPS_STR";
    public static final String FILE_PATH = "FILE_PATH";
    public static final String FILE_NAME = "gps_data.txt";




    public LogFileService() {
        super("LogFileService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


        debug.log("Handling intent");

        String data = intent.getStringExtra(GPS_STR);

        debug.log("Writing " + data);

        GpsLogFile logFile = new GpsLogFile(FILE_NAME);
        logFile.open();
        logFile.write(data);
        logFile.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        debug.log("Created");
    }


}

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;

public class GpsLogFile {

    DebugLog debug = new DebugLog("LogFile");


    private File filePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
    );

    private File logFile = null;
    private String fileName = null;


    private PrintWriter fileOut = null;

    public GpsLogFile(String name) {
        fileName = name;
    }

    public void open() {

        try {

            filePath.mkdirs();  

            if (!isExternalMediaAvailable()) {
                throw new IOException("External media not available.");
            }
            logFile = new File(filePath, fileName);
            //logFile.mkdirs();
            if (!logFile.exists()) {
                logFile.createNewFile();
            }
            fileOut = new PrintWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(logFile.getAbsolutePath(), true)
            );

        } catch (IOException e) {
            debug.log("Unable to open file.");
            debug.log(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void write(String data) {

        debug.log("Writing to " + logFile.getAbsolutePath() + " " + data);

        try {
            fileOut.write(data);
            //fileOut.newLine();
            checkPrintWriterError(fileOut);
            fileOut.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            debug.log("Unable to write");
            debug.log(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        if (null != fileOut) {
            try {
                fileOut.close();
                checkPrintWriterError(fileOut);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkPrintWriterError(PrintWriter writer) throws IOException {
        if (true == writer.checkError()) {
            throw new IOException("Print writer error.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you have the device set so it doesn't allow mounting of the SD card as a drive on the PC, then the SD card is dismounted on the Android device to allow it to be accessed from the PC. Also, if that's the case, after disconnecting the USB it won't immediately re-mount the SD card in the device and it will take time for that to happen.

Comment: Ah, I see. I realized I can access the file consistently through the DDMS.